# Can't install my app on Devices using the APK file

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I recently made an android app. It worked just fine on both my development devices when installed from Android Studio but when I sent the GDrive links or the APK files to my friends for testing, "App not Installed" error showed up.
What's worse, I can't even install the APK directly even on my devices without installing it from android studio.
Why is this happening?
Please help.

Comment: You might want to try it on a device that you have connected with USB, so you can see the logs. It will usually specify why the installation fails.

Comment: Did you sign your app?

Comment: I'm not sure but you have to allow the app to install from unknown sources in your device. Or if you apk is a release version check the troubles in signing the apk

Comment: I haven't signed my APK yet. It's a very basic app, and only uses a third-party library. Is it causing the issues? @blackapps

Comment: @CodeRED Innovations installation from unknown devices is allowed.

Comment: You need to create a keystore and sign your apk.

Comment: Android works this way on purpose. They discourage installs via non Play Store sources. This is the case for multiple reasons. For one thing, it curbs distribution of malware. It also makes it harder to pirate apps. I am not saying that direct distribution is impossible. Just that it is made intentionally difficult. Have you thought about getting a Play Store developer account? It is only $25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a debug APK. For this follow this
`From Android studio above menu select Build -> Build Bundles(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)`

Then wait some time. After build success, you will find your APk here
`\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`

Then share this APK and IT will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create keystore and then use option Build->Generate signed apk. Not signed apk is not installable.